# How do I get Devise's Rememberable module to use http_only for the remember me cookie?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xss, devise, remember-me, httponly

The rails session cookie is `HttpOnly` by default but the `remember_user_token` cookie set by Devise's Rememberable module is not.

As I understand it that cookie when sent will result in the user being issued a new session cookie, so surely it's as vulnerable to XSS.

So is there any way to set it to `HttpOnly`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of @camonz on #rubyonrails I came up with this monkey patch:
https://gist.github.com/749289

In Devise 1.1.3 the cookie options are hardcoded so a monkey patch is all I could think would work.

However, Devise 1.2rc looks like it will allow configuration because it pulls in `resource.cookie_options` (e.g. pulling cookie_options from the User model, so you should be able to set it there somehow - haven't figured that out yet).

P.S. I haven't figured out how to test this yet. To test manually in Chrome switch to the tab the cookie is set in, open Developer Tools with Alt + Cmd + I, switch to the Storage tab, click the item under 'Cookies' (localhost in my case), and look at the HTTP column. There'll be a tick if the cookie is HttpOnly. For reference the rails session cookie, called `_session_id` by default, is HttpOnly by default.

Comment: There's a patch making it default in Devise's master branch now too, so it should be in a version coming soon. https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/pull/735#issuecomment-634501